# how to perform a $lookup op on a field inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

this is the pipeline:

```
{
        $match: {
          _id: new ObjectId(sippetId),
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'sippets',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'ref_sippet',
          as: 'comments'
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'author',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'author'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$author'
      },
      // {
      //   $lookup: {
      //     from: 'users',
      //     localField: 'comments.author',
      //     foreignField: '_id',
      //     as: 'comments.author'
      //   }
      // },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$comments.author',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'sippets',
          localField: 'ref_sippet',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'ref_sippet'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$ref_sippet',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'ref_sippet.author',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'ref_sippet.author'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$ref_sippet.author',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          is: 1,
          author: {
            _id: '$author._id',
            username: '$author.username',
            image: '$author.image',
          },
          blocks: 1,
          language: 1,
          ref_sippet: {
            _id: '$ref_sippet._id',
            author: {
              _id: '$ref_sippet.author._id',
              username: '$ref_sippet.author.username',
              image: '$ref_sippet.author.image',
            },
            blocks: '$ref_sippet.blocks',
            language: '$ref_sippet.language',
            likesCount: '$ref_sippet.likesCount',
            commentsCount: '$ref_sippet.commentsCount',
            toastsCount: '$ref_sippet.toastsCount',
            hashtags: '$ref_sippet.hashtags',
          },
          likesCount: 1,
          commentsCount: 1,
          toastsCount: 1,
          hashtags: 1,
          comments: 1,
        }
      }
```

this is the comment schema:

```
const sippetSchema = new Schema({
    is: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['original', 'toast', 'comment']
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
    blocks: [
        {type: Schema.Types.Mixed}
    ],
    language: {
        type: String,
    },
    ref_sippet: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sippet',
    },
    ...
```

output with and without the lookup pipe:

```
author: {_id: 'someid', username: 'kms', image: null}
blocks: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
comments: []
commentsCount: 1
hashtags: []
is: "original"
language: "javascript"
liked: false
likesCount: 0
ref_sippet: {author: {…}}
toastsCount: 0
_id: "someid"

// without

comments: 
Array(1)
0: 
author: { _id: "someid" }
blocks: [{…}]
commentsCount: 0
createdAt: "2023-05-29T20:27:19.933Z"
hashtags: []
is: "comment"
language: "C-like"
likesCount: 0
ref_sippet: "someid"
toastsCount: 0
updatedAt: "2023-05-29T20:27:19.933Z"
_id: "someid"
```

the commented out pipe is causing the comments field to end up as undefined. i'm fairly new to this, so i might be missing something obvious, sorry in advance :|

note: the authors are there (the refs), as well as some comments. tested without this stage and everything else works fine.

Comment: Please provide some data for input and expected output for better clarification. Thanks.

Comment: i added the comment schema, but i dont know what else to include. as i noted, with the commented out stage im getting undefined for the comments field, and that's basically it